# how to store contact us form details in database programmatically magento 2?

Tags: magento2, contact-form

> I want to store contact us form details in database  programmatically
>   magento 2 ?

Comment: You create that attributes forms in database, you rewrite the `module-contact/controller/index/Post.php` then you save that data in database, you can also do it via an `observer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento does not have this functionality. So you have created a module which has

- Database table
- Model class
- ResoureModel Class
- Collection class

Then for saving the data, you have to rewrite the class module-`contact/controller/index/Post.php`

Answer (score 3):

Us this [free extension](https://github.com/Turiknox/magento2-enquiry-saver) to store data in database.
By using observer can get all data

This module will add a table to your Magento 2 database. As with any third party modules that do this, it is recommended that you backup your database before installation.